# Is it necessary to encrypt the data in the login and registration form with a one-time code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin that the user can login or register by entering a mobile number and receiving a one-time(otp) code via SMS and entering the code in the form.

My plugin is ready and everything is working properly.
I use WordPress nonce for form security .

And now my question:
1- is it necessary to encrypt the otp code when it is sent to the server or not?
2 - If I need to do this, which javascript code will help me?

Comment: You need to keep encrypted connection between user and server, so use `HTTPS`, you can emit free certificate with `LetsEncrypt` service for this.

Comment: "is it necessary", well no. Is it security-wise? Considering it is a one time password, I don't think you need to concern too much about encrypting it